# Modal - Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a question about modals. I have one .cshtml view in which I have button. When I click on this button I want to appear a modal, which is in different .cshtml view. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can create a partial view, and action method in controller and than make an ajax call to get html of partial view to display in your pop-modal. You want code ?

Comment: yes, please. I am not very good in making an ajax

Comment: This link might help you,
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/render-partial-view-as-modal-popup-using-ajax-call-with-json/

Comment: This didn't help me

Comment: please share you .cshtml code

Answer (score 1):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

I add a button in Privacy view, when  I click the button, it will show  a different view in a modal.

HomeController.cs:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
   {    
          public IActionResult Privacy()
          {
                return View();
          }       
          public IActionResult CCC()
          {
                return PartialView("_PartialView");
          }
    }
```

Privacy.cshtml:

```
<button id="btnShowModal" type="button" > Upload </button>
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal">                                            
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
 <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <button  id="btnHideModal" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">  ×</button>
      </div>                                                             
    <div class="modal-body" > 
 </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>


 
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnShowModal").click(function () {
                $.get("@Url.Action("CCC","Home")",
                function(data){$('.modal-body').html(data);})
                $("#Modal").modal('show'); 
            });
 $("#btnHideModal").click(function () {
                $("#Modal").modal('hide');
            });
        });
        
    </script>
```

_PartialView.cshtml:

```
This is a partialview!  You can add what you want.
```

Result:

[image]